# How to update my org from summer 15 to winter 16

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, winter16

I am learning Salesforce and in the newly created salesforce orgs, winter 16 is enabled but my org is two month old and I am not getting the "Lightning Experience" menu as in the newly created orgs.

Please let me know how could I enable the new lightning experience UI in  my org.

FYI - I already marked tick to the option "Enable Lightning Components in Salesforce1 (BETA)".

[image: Lightning]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instance **AP2** is getting Winter 16 release during Oct 17 weekend .. 
[ Check the [release calendar](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/calendar) ]

Until the release you won't see the new Lightning Experience option in your production org.

If you have a sandbox org in Winter 16, you should see the new Lightning experience in it.

Check the [Lightning Experience FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Experience_FAQ) for details on how to access the new Lightning experience in a pre release dev org or in a sandbox.

Comment: Thx ..I don't know about this ..thx for sharing knowledge :)